# Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/tmp.Jtkt5H3v9O/mysqld.sock' (13) in Staging for Rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sockets

When establishing connection in staging console : (DashboardUser is my model)

2.5.0 :006 > DashboardUser.connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):6
Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/tmp.Jtkt5H3v9O/mysqld.sock' (13))

But I am able to ope mysql -uroot -p

````
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:

development:
  <<: *default
  database: api_development
  username: root
  password: 789


MySql configuration is:

```mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      91
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         25 days 21 hours 48 min 43 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 107  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 113  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 106  Queries per second avg: 0.000
````

Comment: can you post your `database.yml` config file?

Comment: added the database.yml

Comment: `rails dbconsole` also doesn't work?

Comment: I am accessing console with RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec  rails c, from there unable to access the sql data. If I open mysql directly over there , then it's able to open and access data.

Comment: in your `database.yml` there is no config for `staging`. Are the username/password is correctly set for this enviornment?

Comment: Thanks nuaky. I have found the issue , some one has hardcoded the incorrect socket name for staging in my database.yml.